# Erro cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java

```
package livraria;

      public class CadastroDeLivro {  
        public static void main(String[] args){  
            Livro livro = new livro ();  
            livro.nome = "java prático";  
            livro.descricao = "novos recursos java";  
            livro.valor = 59.90;  
            livro.isbn = "978-85-66250-46-6";  
    }
}
```

Desbravando Java e Orientação a objetos, quando eu escrevo esse código no meu Eclipse ele aparece a seguinte informação:

> livro cannot be resolved to a type
>   Livro cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro é porque você não possui nenhuma classe com o nome `Livro`. Baseado na sua `main`, você deve criar a classe `Livro` da seguinte maneira:

```
public class Livro{
    String nome;
    String descricao;
    double valor;
    String isbn;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public double getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(double valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public Livro(){}
}
```

Para atribuição dos valores o ideal é fazer desta forma:

```
public class CadastroDeLivro{
    public static void main(String[] args){  

        Livro livro = new Livro();  

        livro.setNome("java prático");
        livro.setDescricao("novos recursos java");          
        livro.setValor(59.90);  
        livro.setIsbn("978-85-66250-46-6");  
      }    
}
```

Comment: Funcionou, Obrigado!